# how to pass index i to data-target in modal. i is declared as index of angular reactive form Array

Tags: html, angularjs, modal-dialog

I am using the reactive form array and want to pass index to the data-target value. i tried using (data-target = "#{{'monthlyPlanSelect'+i}}". but i am getting error. Please help me in let know how to pass the index i in data-target.

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 operational-levers-col"           
     formArrayName="opLevers" *ngFor="let levers of 
       opLevers.controls; let i = index">
      <div [formGroupName]="i">

    <button  class="btn btn-info" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data- 
      target = "#monthlyPlansSelect">
             12 Months plans
          <i class="fas fa-external-link-alt"></i>
     </button>
   </div>
   </div>

    <div formArrayName="opLevers" *ngFor="let levers of opLevers.controls; 
      let i=index">
       <div [formGroupName]="i">
        <div class="modal "
           id="{{'monthlyPlansSelect1'}}"
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Please list the error.

Comment: Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'target' since it isn't a known property of 'button'. ("0 offset-1"> ]data-target = "#{{'monthlyPlansSelect' + i}}"> 12 Months plans "): ng:///MinedetailModule/TiresComponent.html@62:86 at syntaxError (vendor.js:29008) at TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse (vendor.js:43495)

Comment: It would be helpful to update your question with this information.

Comment: I would appreciate, if you help me to address this issue. I tried a lot, but still didn't get solution

Comment: Please help me on this